# How to make a Single exe file from c# assembly and dll?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, exe

I used ILmerge.

And it made a merged_exe file succefully.
(with /zeroPekind option)

But, it does not work.

My work is very simple.
I read a table from a SQLite file and make a text file.
That is it.

I have tried to use "ResolveEventHandler" at the Mains().
It was not work too.

What do I have to do ?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?  What error do you get?

Comment: The first "now work" means.

Comment: very simple message box says "(Korean) problem solving by online and cloes, (the next line) close program (the last line) program debut." that is it.

Comment: The secound "not work" means. (I guess, it has failed to find proper dll. System.Data.SQL.dll even though I wrote all the needed reflection codes at the proper place.  )

Comment: The second one should be "Jeffrey Richter"'s idea.

Comment: I put an option at ilmerge. It gave me a one step further result. But, that is it. It does not make the file I have wanted(txt). Instead it gave me..."can"t find that *ucking dll" message again. Full command I used at the black screen is "ilmerge /out:myDestinatination myOrginal myDll /zeropekind /targetplatform:v4". I gave it up all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Costura.Fody. It works great.

```
Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Here is steps to add using VS.

1. Go to Tool -> Nuget Package Manage -> Package Manager Console
2. Make sure your project is selected as Default project in console
3. Type command "Install-Package Costura.Fody" then hit enter.
4. Compile and run your app
5. Your exe will be ready
6. However you can customize it with FodyWeavers.xml

Comment: Thanks comment. But, what is it ? I have no idea at all.

Comment: It is nuget package to embed all required dlls, assets into single exe. You just install this for your project via nuget, and will get single output. you can learn more here https://github.com/Fody/Costura

Comment: Yeah.. I just googled it from your comment. My problem is I do not know what the *eck is "NuGet". Anyways, I'll try it out..... Thanks.

Comment: "Successfully installed 'Costura.Fody 1.3.3' to mySQLite001" What do I have to do ??

Comment: OK. I saw it. the empty "FodyWeavers.xml" that should be the hardest part of all I guess. Thanks.

Comment: By default, it embed all dependencies automatically, even if you don't edit this xml. Try to execute your exe independently from other folder Or check size of final exe.

Comment: Naah, It is not woking too. I guess, I have to kind so called "options". Thanks.