# Issue with building single small exe file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the older version of the visual studio, it was possible to build a small "Hello World" application that has a single .exe file and size around 200KB. I started to use a new version of Visual Studio and I have with this simple task.

When I build it with parameters:

```
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

The output is single .exe, but with the size around 25MB. When I build it as "Framework dependent", the .exe is around 150KB, but it has additional 2 .json configuration files.

Is it possible now to publish a single small .exe file without the .json configuration files in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why does it matter if your executable is 150KB, or 200KB or even a few megabytes?

Comment: Well, I am having multiple small tools in C# to do various simple post-process of images/text/assets. It is just not practical for the GIT repository, to have 20 small tools that take 450MB, instead of 2MB.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't store binaries in your git repo though. Also, your compiled single file application shouldn't need those json config files making it small enough. Just make sure to not compile with `--single-file` as that will bundle the runtime alongside your app

Comment: Sometimes it is handy if the tools have a few KB and you want to sync workspace between multiple devices. Probably some type of my OCD, that I do not like the mess in the folders from the .json files :D Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @LukášMichalec, maybe you can refer to [How to make a Single exe file from c# assembly and dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178257/how-to-make-a-single-exe-file-from-c-sharp-assembly-and-dll) to produce a single exe.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising

Comment: @LukášMichalec, is any update?

Comment: Using Costura Fody solved my issue :)

Comment: @LukášMichalec, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved. I have posted an answer, you click '✔' to mark mark the appropriate reply as the answer, which can help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @LukášMichalec, is any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Costura.Fody to make a single exe without another file.

The following link is a similar question, you can refer to it to solve this problem.

[How to make a Single exe file from c# assembly and dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178257/how-to-make-a-single-exe-file-from-c-sharp-assembly-and-dll)